# Map 'ec2-register snapshot' syntax onto 'register-image AMI 'syntax using awscli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

What is the correct syntax for mapping a snapshot onto an AMI using awscli? 
More explicitly, how do I map the old syntax
'ec2-register -s snap-9abc1234 --kernel 99abcdef' onto the new syntax 
'aws ec2 --register-image' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the following:

```
aws ec2 register-image --kernel-id <your-kernel> --root-device-name /dev/sda1 --block-device-mappings [list in JSON shown below]

      [
        {
          "VirtualName": "string",
          "DeviceName": "string",
          "Ebs": {
            "SnapshotId": "string",
            "VolumeSize": integer,
            "DeleteOnTermination": true|false,
            "VolumeType": "standard"|"io1",
            "Iops": integer
          },
          "NoDevice": "string"
        }
        ...
      ]
```

You can run `aws ec2 register-image help` for help on the command.

Make sure you are using the `awscli` python package on not the `aws` package as that one is different (not the official one)

Here's a link to the github repo:

https://github.com/aws/aws-cli

Comment: Thank you @Rico.
I came up with the following....
    aws ec2 register-image \
       --profile xxxx \
       --name 'a meaningful name' \
       --description 'a meaningful description' \
       --architecture i386 \
       --root-device-name /dev/sda1 \
       --kernel-id aki-9999999 \
       --block-device-mappings '[{"DeviceName": "/dev/sda1", "Ebs": {"SnapshotId": "snap-xxxxxxxx", "VolumeSize": 8}}, {"VirtualName": "ephemeral0", "DeviceName": "/dev/sdb"}]'